# API To Get Camera Info On Android

Tags: android, api, android-camera

How can I get the camera info of the ***Rear Camera*** on Android ?
Any API that would do it for me ?
I need -

- `Manufacturer Name`
- `Sensor Codemane`
- `Sensor Size`
- `Aperture`
- `is Auto-Focus Available`
- `is Optical Image Stabilization Available`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**Camera.getCameraInfo(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, cameraInfo);**

Answer (score 0):

To access camera follow this.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

And to get camera parameters check this.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html